# Why doesn't a pdf file view in a seperate tab in internet explorer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a function which display a pdf file. Im using Internet Explorer and it's upto date. I tried to do it in two computers. In one browser it asks to open through a pdf reader while other one opens a tab and display an empty page. I've tried many codes found in the internet even in stackoverflow. But nothing works as i want. Here i have added my code. Please take a look at it.

> Linkbutton click event

```
protected void pdfViewLOP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "viewPDF.aspx"));
}
```

> code in new page which pdf should be displayed

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         string name = Session["name"].ToString();
         string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/filesPDF/" + name);
         WebClient client = new WebClient();
         Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(FilePath);
         if (buffer != null)
         {
              Response.Clear();
              Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
              Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
              Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WebMsgBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely due to settings on the client machine, specifically Adobe preferences.

> To change the default PDF open behavior when using a web browser:
>
> Choose Edit—>Preferences
>
> Select the Internet category from the list on the left
>
> To display the PDF in the browser, check "Display in browser"
>
> To open PDFs from the web directly in Acrobat, uncheck "Display in browser:

See [this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2007/08/how_do_i_open_a_pdf_in_acrobat_i/) and [this article](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html).

Also note: To display a PDF in your browser, your cache control headers must allow the browser to create a temporary copy of the PDF.  If you are setting cache hints to prevent caching (e.g. if you application contains sensitive pages) you might be better off letting the user download the PDF and view it offline.

Comment: i tried as in the articles, but there is no adobe extension installd in the browser